# PDF generator, table and graph, PHP or Javascript

Tags: php, pdf, graph

I need a PDF generator for tables and graph, too. I use domPDF on server side for the tables and it works fine, and jspdf on client side for the graph. (I use RGraph for the graph) But now I want one PDF with tables and graph, too. Where should I start, on client side or server side? I tried generate PDF with graph on server side, but I failed, and it is difficult to generating tables with jspdf, I give it up, when I can't write "ő" letter, but playing with boxes and texts not seem to be safe.

Comment: just render all the graphs as images and embed in the template for domPDF.. simples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved same issue some time ago by generating graphs as images on server side with http://www.pchart.net/ and then including these images in PDF file.

Comment: It seems to be a good way, I can generate the image. I will test it with the domPDF.